# Align labels on border of rectangle

Tags: javascript, math

I have the following SVG I am drawing using the javasript code below. It will align the labels on a circular route. I want to have a second version where the labels are going to be an the edge of an rectangle but still in the middle of each section of the circual pie chart. I am not able to figure out how to calculate the positions, can anyone help?

[Current SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1GrB.png)

Current Code:

```
// height/width = size of the element containing the circle
// celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter = distance to the center of the circle
const circleAngle = (2 * Math.PI) / 24;
CELESTIAL_DIRECTIONS.forEach((currentDirection, index) => {
    const newIndex = index + 2;

    elemAttrs[currentDirection] = {
        transform: `rotate(${360 - newAngle}, ${
            Math.cos(circleAngle * newIndex) *
                (width * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
            width * 0.5
        }, ${
            Math.sin(circleAngle * newIndex) *
                (height * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
            height * 0.5
        })`,
        x:
            Math.cos(circleAngle * newIndex) *
                (width * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
            width * 0.5,
        y:
            Math.sin(circleAngle * newIndex) *
                (height * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
            height * 0.5,
    };
        
});
```

[Wanted result SVG - Not perfectly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbCb0.png)

**New code for the ellipsis, circle, square and rectangle**

```
    const a = width * 0.5;
    const b = height * 0.5;
    let x;
    let y;

    const ro =
        pieChartKind === 'E' || pieChartKind === 'R'
            ? (a * b) /
              Math.sqrt((b * Math.cos(currentAngle)) ** 2 + (a * Math.sin(currentAngle)) ** 2)
            : 1;

    const factor =
        pieChartKind === 'S' || pieChartKind === 'R'
            ? Math.sqrt(1.0) /
              Math.max(
                    Math.abs(ro * Math.cos(currentAngle)),
                    Math.abs(ro * Math.sin(currentAngle)),
              )
            : 1;

    if (pieChartKind === 'E') {
        x = factor * ro * Math.cos(currentAngle) + width * 0.5;
        y = factor * ro * Math.sin(currentAngle) + height * 0.5;
    } else {
        x = factor * ro * Math.cos(currentAngle) * a + width * 0.5;
        y = factor * ro * Math.sin(currentAngle) * b + height * 0.5;
    }

    return { x, y };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try normalizing sinusoidal parts of coordinates by the larger component.

```
const factor = Math.sqrt(2.0) / Math.max(
    Math.abs(Math.cos(circleAngle * newIndex)), 
    Math.abs(Math.sin(circleAngle * newIndex))
)

elemAttrs[currentDirection] = {
    transform: `rotate(${360 - newAngle}, ${
        factor * Math.cos(circleAngle * newIndex) *
            (width * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
        width * 0.5
    }, ${
        factor * Math.sin(circleAngle * newIndex) *
            (height * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
        height * 0.5
    })`,
    x:
    factor * Math.cos(circleAngle * newIndex) *
            (width * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
        width * 0.5,
    y:
    factor * Math.sin(circleAngle * newIndex) *
            (height * 0.5 * celestialDirectionsDistanceToCenter) +
        height * 0.5,
};
```

Comment: Thank you @ardget, this works just as expected!!! Math is such a beatiful thing, if you understand it... :D

Comment: Hi @ardget, I have a follow up questions on this topic. I am calculating equal angle sections of a ellipse and would like to extend the end of the lines so they meet the border of the rectangle. I am using the following code to calculate the points at a specific angle. I also use this to calcualte it based on a circle and square with the factor you mentioned above. But just using the same factor for the ellipse isnt working, because it will stretch the points.

I edited my question above and added the new code.